# Has video chat for GoogleWebRTC broken with iOS 13.4?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webrtc, metal

I have got video chat working via GoogleWebRTC with my old iPhone 6 but no matter what I do I cannot seem to get either the incoming or outgoing video to render on my iPhone XS running iOS 13.4. This is after 10 straight days effort of trying to make it work.

I have seen one or two other posts regarding people who can't seem to get it to work and I was just wondering if anyone out there CAN get video chat to work via GoogleWebRTC on an iOS 13.4 device.

With the release of iOS 13.4 perhaps something has broken?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. For empirical evidence supporting my hypothesis that there is an issue with iOS 13, please see the end of this discussion: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216051/discussion-between-vinod-kumar-and-albinmrngstar

Comment: Here is someone else with the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621526/rtcmtlvideoview-not-supported-in-iphone-11-series

Comment: Hi @John Paul, was able to generate the latest WebRTC.framework ??

Comment: Any update on the manual WebRTC.framework for iOS ??

Comment: Hi Balaji so the manual build works and so I recommend you go down that route. All the best!

Comment: Hi John Paul. I'm having some issues with the manual build. Can I contact you regarding this ?? Here's my email: info.balajir@gmail.com.