# RTCMTLVideoView not supported in iPhone 11 series

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, ios13, iphone11

I'm working on Video calls using WebRTC. I've used RTCMTLVideoView to render the remote's video in the app. Except iPhone 11 series devices, all other devices were working fine.

```
  #if arch(arm64) // Using metal (arm64 only)
    remoteRenderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame: showInView.bounds)
  #endif
```

I'm checking the issue in iPhone 11 Pro 13.3.1 & iPhone XS 13.2.3 and iPhone 6 12.3. But iPhone 11 alone getting this issue. Do we have any solutions for this Remote Video rendering issue?

Answer (score 7):

Great to see I am not going crazy and this really is an issue! Not too sure why your and my [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611952/has-video-chat-for-googlewebrtc-broken-with-ios-13-4) were downvoted.

I have switched to using an RTCEAGLVideoView instead on my iPhone XS iOS 13.4. This works for local rendering. I cannot get remote rendering to work and am unsure if the problem is with WebRTC or with my implementation. However RTCMTLVideoView is clearly broken.

This week I am hoping to start diving into the WebRTC objective C [source code](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/docs/native-code/ios/index.md) to see if I can find anything.

**EDIT:** I have filed a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11727) with google. Could you (and anyone else having this issue) upvote the bug report so we can get Google on this ASAP? Thanks!

**EDIT:** Ok so the issue was that the cocoapods version of webrtc has been deprecated and people need to manually build the framework. Then this issue disappears. Good luck everyone!

Comment: Sure. will do. Is GoogleWebRTC '1.1.29400'  deprecated ?

Comment: That seems to be the case. It is unfortunate that this fact seems to be mentioned nowhere except in this obscure part of the internet: https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/Ozvbd0p7Q1Y

Comment: I am currently performing a manual build of the latest release of WebRTC and will report back if this solves the issue. It takes a long time to download. The instructions for a manual build can be found here: https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/docs/native-code/ios/index.md

Comment: Thanks John. Sure will check it out. Please let me know if you find any solutions. Feel free to ping me: info.balajir@gmail.com

Comment: I'm also working on a video call pwa using vue.js, as far as I know it can be run in all os, including android, ios, win and linux.

Comment: last time when I use the google flutter web technology to develop the same application, it can only be run on chrome browser, so I guess the 'google' things may not be compatible with apple devices.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I was able to fix the issue by replacing **GoogleWebRTC from Cocoapods** and updated with **Manual WebRTC.framework**.

As per discussion in the [WebRTC bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11727#makechanges), GoogleWebRTC from Cocoapods **DEPRECATED** and no longer updated with new changes.

Use this [link](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/docs/native-code/ios/index.md) to build the manual framework for WebRTC from the latest source and remove your GoogleWebRTC from Pods and add manual WebRTC.framework

Thanks [John Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13811700/john-paul) for your timely help.